# Activiating different E4 command handlers depending on current viewer selection

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

I am implementing a simple E4 part with a `TreeViewer` backed by `TreeNode`s with different value types `Foo` and `Bar`.

I now want to add an `IOpenListener` to the `TreeViewer` that executes an open command:

```
treeViewer.addOpenListener(event -> {
  ...
  Object selected value = ((TreeNode) event.getSelection()).getValue();
  ...
});
```

Now  I can get a command from the `ECommandService` and execute it using the `EHandlerService`.

However, I want a **different handler** to execute, **depending on** whether the **selected value** is a `Foo` or a `Bar`; while all handlers correspond to the same logical command ("Open"), the handler actually executed needs to depend on the selection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is only be one handler for a part.

You can use the `EHandlerService.activateHandler` method to activate different handlers, but this would require you to be constantly activating and deactivating handlers using a selection listener as the selection changed.

Comment: Yes, I know about per-part handlers, but I need a finer granularity. Achieving this with `activateHandler` would mean my `IOpenListener` would need to know about the mapping from selection types to handlers, which is some hard-coding I would rather avoid. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: There is no finer granularity in e4. Parts are the smallest thing it deals with.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar use case in a project a while back and came up with a '`generic composite handler`' that is capable of dispatching the `event context` to the right/actual/concrete handler instance.
For example, the composite handler is instantiated knowing all the handlers it should be dispatching to.

Comment: That sounds neat. It could get the `IEclipseContext` injected in `@Execute`/@CanExecute` and then use tags to get the right handler base on the selection’s type (assuming the delegatees are tagged with their supported selection types). The only thing that is awkward then is that you need to manually merge `visibleWhen` expressions. Did you have `visibleWhen` expressions in your case as well and did you maybe come up with a better solution?

Comment: @AndreasSewe visibleWhen expressions are to control the visual representation of a command (toolbar items, menu items). Do you mean the enabledWhen state of handlers? I used the CanExecute method to determine which handler to execute.

Comment: No, I meant `visibleWhen`. Use case: A tree viewer with three kinds of nodes: `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Quux`. For `Foo` and `Bar` an "Open" action makes sense, but with a different handler. But for `Quux` nodes I don't want to show the menu item at all, as there is no enabled handler; form the, the active selection is neither a `Foo` nor a `Bar` but a `Quux`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Not sure if it fits into your UI style/behavior: but omitting visibleWhen will make the menu item disabled if no handler is active,

Comment: I ended up implementing a delegate handler that uses `ContextInjectionFactory.invoke` to invoke its delegatees, which are registered by given the handler a special tag in the `fragement.e4xmi`. Works nicely. The one draw-back is that the delegatee handlers still need a command (required by `MHandler`), which cannot be just the delegate handler's command to avoid clashes. This dummy command pollutes the Quick Access bar, i.e., it is user visible but shouldn't be. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need the delegatees to be registered via model fragments? I would hard-wire the delegatees in the delegate handler if their functionality is scoped/limited to the viewer events, i.e. not used anywhere else in the system.